# Php loop through large array data

Tags: php, arrays

I have a users array having more then 16k records. So I need to process users array to send push notification but every time it sucks server execution time.

Please help me how to process array data something like delayed jobs so server will not sucks.

I tried to use array chunk but it still not work is there any way to use something like delayed job.

Comment: Try `php_value max_execution_time 1800` in file vhost configuration or in file `.htaccess`. It increases the max execution time (cpu usage) to 30 minutes.

Comment: We need more info about your setup. Do you have access to a queueing system?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to use the sleep function [sleep()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

After, let's say 500 values, sleep(1).

Comment: Still server time out, is there a way to use a delayed job like we make send_notification function to be processed in delay like first 500 processed then next and so on...

Comment: how should this help to decrease the execution time?

Comment: @Wiimm Just try it out (The script will run for 5 min without any time out):

<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 5 * 60; $i++) {
    sleep(1);
}

echo 'completed';

Comment: @AmanKamboj please show us the part of the code causing the time out.

Comment: @JustPilot Let me explain the code structure again, I user table with access token saved in user table. From My sql i queried all users (More than 16k records).
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $device_id=$row["fcm_token"];
            // Push notification code ....
           }

Comment: @AmanKamboj are you running the script on linux? Another way to solve your problem by using the set_time_limit function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php. Try to set set_time_limit(0); within your script.

Comment: @JustPilot: The CPU consumption is used for the execution time. A sleep does not change this consumption (or only minimally due to additional overhead). That's why your test works as well as slow and large downloads where the CPU does almost nothing. However, this does not increase the execution time limit.